# Flexbox switching order of divs on resize

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I'm looking at this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-layout-material-seed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) about Flexbox in Angular, I noticed that on resize, the `second-section` falls below the `first-section`. Is there any way that I can make it lays on top of the `first-section` (on resize), without modifying the html?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example above it changes because of
`fxLayout="row"` and `fxLayout.xs="column"`

To custom change the ordering you will need `fxFlexOrder`

```
<div fxFlexOrder='1' fxFlexOrder.xs='3'></div>
<div fxFlexOrder='2' fxFlexOrder.xs='2'></div>
<div fxFlexOrder='3' fxFlexOrder.xs='1'></div>
```

[fxFlex Documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation)
[fxFlex-Responsive Documentation](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API)